# CopyOnWriteArrayList<Integer> в итерации

Tags: java, многопоточность

Столкнулась с такой проблемой

Есть `CopyOnWriteArrayList<Integer> stations = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();`

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы, перебирая ее и изменяя одновременно в итерации, перебор как бы подстраивался под новое значение:

```
for (Integer i : stations) {
   //some code
   stations.addAll(some collection);
   Collections.sort(stations);
}
```

Но, к сожалению, код выше не работает так, как задумывалось. Он заканчивает итерацию в соответствие с неизмененным, бывшим списком. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно это реализовать?

Comment: Данный цикл работает через итератор, который предоставляет снимок состояния коллекции в момент его получения. То есть, если после получения итератора, начать добавлять что-то в коллекцию, эти изменения никак не отразятся на итераторе, так как он содержит "снимок" коллекции в момент получения самого итератора.